# Self-hosted spherical (360-degree) image viewer?

Tags: images, image-viewer, self-hosted

I'm taking 360-degree pictures.

I want to share them.

I don't want people viewing them to install any apps / any software.

Just mine webserver running **___** and me sharing a private link.

I've found this - https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-to-share-a-360-degree-panoramic-photo - with some suggestions but maybe in 2016 there is a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most modern web browsers you can have a 360 degree panorama viewer with just a little JavaScript in a HTML5 WebGL web page.

There is a good example [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2014/12/10/html5-webgl-360-degrees-panorama-viewer-with-three-js/) which makes use of the [three.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three.js) open source library.

### The code from the above page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                margin: 0;
            }
            canvas{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%
            }
        </style>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r69/three.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

            var manualControl = false;
            var longitude = 0;
            var latitude = 0;
            var savedX;
            var savedY;
            var savedLongitude;
            var savedLatitude;

            // panoramas background
            var panoramasArray = ["01.jpg","02.jpg","03.jpg","04.jpg","05.jpg","06.jpg"];
            var panoramaNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*panoramasArray.length);

            // setting up the renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            // creating a new scene
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // adding a camera
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

            // creation of a big sphere geometry
            var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 100, 40);
            sphere.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));

            // creation of the sphere material
            var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
            sphereMaterial.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(panoramasArray[panoramaNumber])

            // geometry + material = mesh (actual object)
            var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, sphereMaterial);
            scene.add(sphereMesh);

            // listeners
            document.addEventListener("mousedown", onDocumentMouseDown, false);
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove, false);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", onDocumentMouseUp, false);

               render();

               function render(){

                requestAnimationFrame(render);

                if(!manualControl){
                    longitude += 0.1;
                }

                // limiting latitude from -85 to 85 (cannot point to the sky or under your feet)
                    latitude = Math.max(-85, Math.min(85, latitude));

                // moving the camera according to current latitude (vertical movement) and longitude (horizontal movement)
                camera.target.x = 500 * Math.sin(THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - latitude)) * Math.cos(THREE.Math.degToRad(longitude));
                camera.target.y = 500 * Math.cos(THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - latitude));
                camera.target.z = 500 * Math.sin(THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - latitude)) * Math.sin(THREE.Math.degToRad(longitude));
                camera.lookAt(camera.target);

                // calling again render function
                renderer.render(scene, camera);

            }

            // when the mouse is pressed, we switch to manual control and save current coordinates
            function onDocumentMouseDown(event){

                event.preventDefault();

                manualControl = true;

                savedX = event.clientX;
                savedY = event.clientY;

                savedLongitude = longitude;
                savedLatitude = latitude;

            }

            // when the mouse moves, if in manual contro we adjust coordinates
            function onDocumentMouseMove(event){

                if(manualControl){
                    longitude = (savedX - event.clientX) * 0.1 + savedLongitude;
                    latitude = (event.clientY - savedY) * 0.1 + savedLatitude;
                }

            }

            // when the mouse is released, we turn manual control off
            function onDocumentMouseUp(event){

                manualControl = false;

            }

            // pressing a key (actually releasing it) changes the texture map
            document.onkeyup = function(event){

                panoramaNumber = (panoramaNumber + 1) % panoramasArray.length
                sphereMaterial.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(panoramasArray[panoramaNumber])

                }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

- Google VR View: https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview#getting_started_with_vr_view_for_the_web

It looks to me like this is early stage *(because of the whole variety of debug messages)* and it also uses `THREE.js`

---

- https://pannellum.org/documentation/overview/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.ideaspacevr.org - a self-hosted open source php software with 360 degrees panorama themes